# Why does my iPad require me to tap 'OK' for a 6 digit PIN, but my iPhone does not?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm using a 6 digit PIN on both my iPad and my iPhone.

Both are running iOS 9.0.1.

My iPhone takes the six-digit PIN and opens to the home screen.

My iPad takes the six-digit PIN and then waits for me to touch OK before I can go to the home screen.

I have the iPhone 6S and the 3rd Gen. iPad

So,**why does my iPad require me to tap 'OK' for a 6 digit PIN, but my iPhone does not?**

Comment: I think that on your iPhone you have a 6 digit code, but on your iPad you have a custom alphanumeric code made of 6digit. In the first case you don't need to push ok. In the second case you have a classical keyboard not the only digit keyboard. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your iPhone, you have a 6 digit code, replacing the prior 4 digit code.

On your iPad, you have an alphanumeric password, which just happens to consist of just 6 digits. Alphanumeric passwords on iOS are just like other passwords in that you have to confirm when you have finished typing.